# How to add comma in a number in logical way

Tags: php

I don't know how to convert a number.
`number_format()` didn't help me.
This is what I want to do...

```
from 1 to 0,01
from 12 to 0,12
from 1234 to 12,34
from 12345 to 123,45
from 123456 to 1.234,56
from 1000000 to 10.000,00
from 123456789 to 1.234.567,89
etc.
```

Thanks :)

Comment: The first two dont really make sense

Comment: You can divide by 100 with the [`/` arithmetic operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php), if that's your question :-?

Comment: x/100 and then use `number_format`? But why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Divide by `100` first, then you can use [`number_format`](http://php.net/number_format):

```
$number = 1;
echo number_format($number / 100, 2, ",", "."); // 2 decimals, "," and "." as seperators
// gives 0,01
```

Comment: Beat me to it! `number_format(123456789 / 100, 2, ",", ".");`

Comment: I've edited to include the function definition, as I feel this makes things clearer